# Firebase: Could the association between "Notification Key" and "User ID" replace the one between "Firebase Token" and "user id"?

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

When using Firebase Cloud Messages, usually I store in my database the assocation of user and device id (firebase token). If I want to use "Notification Key" in order to group multiple device of the same user, can I store the notification key without the device token in my server?
Ut should be useless to store the device token when using notification keys, is that correct?